# SQL Server - xp_cmdshell timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout, xp-cmdshell

I have an SP that invokes `xp_cmdshell` to call an .exe.  The .exe has logic to avoid requiring user input, but a few still slip through, which cause the SP to hang indefinitely and leave things in a bad state.

[image]

Is there a way to add timeout logic to the `xp_cmdshell` call, so that the .exe call is aborted, gracefully if possible, after 60 seconds (i.e. equivalent of CTRL-Z or CTRL-C in cmd prompt)?

**SP**

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE RC.USR_SP_REFRESHEXCELFILE (
      @SourceFilePath VARCHAR(1000)
    , @SourceFileName VARCHAR(255)
    , @TargetFilePath VARCHAR(1000)
    , @TargetFileName VARCHAR(255)
    , @Result INTEGER OUTPUT -- 0 = success, 1 = failure
) AS
BEGIN 
    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE 
       @ExcelRefreshProgramLocation VARCHAR(1000),
       @CommandString VARCHAR(8000)

    -- Get exe path
    SET @ExcelRefreshProgramLocation =  <...some location...>

    -- Set command string
    SET @CommandString = 
        @ExcelRefreshProgramLocation + ' ' + 
        @SourceFilePath + ' "' + 
        @SourceFileName + '" ' + 
        @TargetFilePath + ' "' + 
        @TargetFileName + '"' -- quotes not working with file paths

    -- Allow advanced options to be changed
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
    RECONFIGURE;  
  
    -- Enable command shell
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
    RECONFIGURE;  

    -- Execute command
    EXEC @Result = xp_cmdshell @CommandString;

    -- Disable command shell
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;  
    RECONFIGURE;  
  
    -- Prevent advanced options from being changed
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;  
    RECONFIGURE;  

END
```

Comment: Probably need to rethink why you are using `xp_cmdshell` in the first place, it has security implications and is difficult to debug. T-SQL is not a generalized scripting language, don't use it as such. Powershell is much better placed for these types of things, if you need to run it from SQL Server then create SQL Agent Job written in Powershell.

Comment: Good point, thanks.